# How to generate an executable from an AWS-chalice application?

Tags: python, chalice

I have an [AWS-chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice) project and I want to generate an executable form this project.

So instead of running `chalice local` to start a local server, I just call the executable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution, based on [Pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller):

1. Manually inject environment variables
2. Manually start local server
3. Manually intercept and handle special events (like SQS, Cron, ...)
4. Compile the code with [Pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller)

call this code from at the end of `app.py`:

```
import os
from chalice.cli import CLIFactory
from chalice.local import LocalDevServer
def start_standalone(app):
    stage = os.environ.get("stage", "dev")
    print(f"initializing standalone server: {stage}")
    factory = CLIFactory(project_dir=os.getcwd(), debug=True, environ=os.environ, profile="dev")
    config = factory.create_config_obj(
        chalice_stage_name=stage
    )
    os.environ = {**os.environ, **config.environment_variables}

    host = os.environ.get("host", '127.0.0.1')
    port = os.environ.get("port", 8000)
    s = LocalDevServer(app, config=config, host=host, port=port)
    s.serve_forever()
    #handle_special_events(app) # to handle SQS and Cron; didn't include the code as it is not the main goal of this question
```

At this stage, you can run `python app.py` to make sure that your changes are valid.

Then using [Pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) run `pyinstaller -F --add-data="./.chalice/config.json:.chalice" app.py`

PS: you might want to move the part about environment variables to the beginning of `app.py` so it can be used in your initialization.